# What's the SpecialFolder enum member that has the base directory for the user?

Tags: c#, .net, mscorlib

As far as I understand these are the best examples for each of the `SpecialFolder` members:

```
Desktop                 C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Desktop
Programs                C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Start Menu\Programs
Personal                C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\My Documents
MyDocuments             C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\My Documents
Favorites               C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Favorites
Startup                 C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
Recent                  C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Recent
SendTo                  C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\SendTo
StartMenu               C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Start Menu
MyMusic                 C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\My Documents\My Music
DesktopDirectory        C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Desktop
MyComputer
Templates               C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Templates
ApplicationData         C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Application Data
LocalApplicationData    C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\LocalSettings\Application Data
InternetCache           C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files
Cookies                 C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Cookies
History                 C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\Local Settings\History
CommonApplicationData   C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
System                  C:\WINDOWS\system32
ProgramFiles            C:\Program Files
MyPictures              C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard\My Documents\My Pictures
CommonProgramFiles      C:\Program Files\Common Files
```

(Assuming the username is called *ibboard*)

So, there's no way to get the base user directory `C:\Documents and Settings\ibboard`? Really??? Don't tell me I need to "cd .." please.

Answer (score 3):

You missed to mention `UserProfile`, which is available since .NET 4, which will yield the user's directory:

```
string userDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) (emphasis mine):

> The user's profile folder. **Applications should not create files or folders at this level**; they should put their data under the locations referred to by ApplicationData. Added in the .NET Framework 4.

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems that the OP is using .NET 3.5 of lower on Windows XP/2000. They may not have access to this enum member.

Comment: Possibly yes. Otherwise the answer would be: not possible. (And if so, it is time to replace it)