# How to open the tablet-mode on-screen-keyboard in C#?

Tags: c#, on-screen-keyboard

I want to start the new On-Screen-Keyboard (OSK) using code. You can find this one in the taskbar:

[image: New-OSK-Taskbar]

(if not there you find it by right clicking the taskbar).

I have already tried the regular:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

But I want to start the other one (not in window mode). Here you see which OSK I want and which one not:

[image: OSK wanted version distinction]

How can I start that version? And how can I start it in a certain setting (if possible)?

Comment: Unless this is related to a very recent version of Windows that I'm not aware of, this isn't a "new OSK". This is just the touch keyboard that is available only while in tablet-mode; it has been the case for along time. I edited your question title. Feel free to roll the edit back or edit further if this doesn't reflect what you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By starting a process in command-line**

I believe you want to start the following process in Windows 10, as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e3e1eb6-ad12-455c-84e9-b5a78a893ac4/open-on-screen-keyboard-in-windows-10-via-vba?forum=accessdev):

```cs
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe"
```

As suggested by @bernard-vander-beken, it's better to use

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles)
```

to produce the `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\"` part of the path to fit different install locations.

**Through an API**

The previous command-line seems to work in inconsistent ways, in particular it doesn't work twice if the `tabtip.exe` process is already running.

I found this snippet by @torvin on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition), which you can use to programmatically show the on-screen keyboard **after** you've started the `tabtip.exe` using the command-line solution, otherwise it fails with a `COM` exception.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uiHostNoLaunch = new UIHostNoLaunch();
        var tipInvocation = (ITipInvocation)uiHostNoLaunch;
        tipInvocation.Toggle(GetDesktopWindow());
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(uiHostNoLaunch);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("4ce576fa-83dc-4F88-951c-9d0782b4e376")]
    class UIHostNoLaunch
    {
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("37c994e7-432b-4834-a2f7-dce1f13b834b")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface ITipInvocation
    {
        void Toggle(IntPtr hwnd);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
}
```

Comment: To make it work with diferrent install locations, consider using the special folder API.  E.g. Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles). Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588217/whats-the-specialfolder-enum-member-that-has-the-base-directory-for-the-user

Comment: Thanks what you suggested seems to be the correct thing. However if I try to start the _tabtip.exe_ nothing happens. (Tried also by starting it manually from the folder)
The keyboard icon on the taskbar still works however and starts it correctly. Is there something else that I need to start the _tabtip.exe_?

Comment: are you in tablet mode? Also you might need to start it as admin according to the linked post. Not sure why though.

Comment: Somehow starting as admin also did not work for me. Do you have any idea what else it could be?

Comment: @GionSnow I edited my answer with more research. I'm still not satisfied as it's a bit hacky and undocumented but it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want this solution:
[Stack Overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48545074/18272213)

which brings up the tablet touch keyboard, rather than the on screen keyboard

Once you create the static `OnScreenKeyboard` class (shown in the thread) you can call it like `OnScreenKeyboard.ToggleVisibility();`
Or `OnScreenKeyboard.Show();`
[image: Touch Keyboard]