# How to open windows on screen keyboard (tabtip.exe) from node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, electron

I am developing application for Zebra tablet and need to open the windows onscreen virtual keyboard.
The application is written as electron app with react front end.
I've searched for the on the npm repo and only package I've found is [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-windows-osk) .
unfortunately this does not seem to work for me. can someone suggest solution?
Thanks in advance !

**EDIT:**

after more digging I found that the process I want to open is tabtip.exe
so I am using build in nodes build in child_process to run the executable

now Im facing similar issue as in
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747008/how-to-open-the-tablet-mode-on-screen-keyboard-in-c)
the process is executed and it is running in the background, but I am still unable to open the keyboard.

Comment: Does not work - how ? Do you get an error? Please include it in your question using the "edit" link.